# nvarchar(max) to decimal(24,6) results in NULL other conversions fail

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Currently loading data via SSIS into a staging table with all fields set as nvarchar(max) (due to poor quality of incoming data such as text in date and numeric fields). Then transferring the data into a second table with the appropriate data types set.

Question is, why does text stored as nvarchar(MAX) in the first table fail when I attempt to merge it into a date() field in the second table. Yet text in the first table results in a NULL when I merge it into a  decimal(24,6) in the second table?

Is there a way to get the two scenarios to behave consistently?

Comment: Can you show some example data? And why is this magged MySQL?

Comment: Can you include some of the SQL that you are using to move the data from the first table to the second table.

Comment: Just tried to produce some examples and the process has handled the incorrect datatype 3 different ways on 3 different files. I suspect it has something to do with how SSIS initially identifys the datatype when it first loads (depending on how far down the incorrect data type is). I'll check this out and re-post a new question with full examples and code if necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nvarchar(max) becomes DT_NTEXT in the SSIS pipeline buffer. Nvarchar(max) is an Object type, so take a look at the type of variable/conversion you are trying to insert into. Some conversions are not possible.

Take a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0f3665cb-4645-484d-ae2f-4cc0abca8107/converting-data-from-ntext-to-dbtimestamp-with-ssis)